# "Get [my app name]" on Facebook goes to wrong URL

Tags: iphone, facebook

When I post something from my iPhone app to Facebook everything works great except the part under the post where it has "Like" "Comment" "Get [My App Name".

When I click on "Get [My App Name]" I go to a URL that is mine, but with a typo in it and I get a 404 page.  I tried changing EVERY URL setting in the App Dev page in Basic, Auth, and Advanced.  None of these change the URL for the "Get [My App Name]" link.

Please help, I've been trying to figure this out for a few months now and it seems like an easy fix.

Thank You.

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

I figured this out if anyone else is having issues.

It is NOT a Facebook issue, but rather was a variable set by me in the ShareKit SDK in the file, "SHKConfig.h":

## define SHKMyAppURL @"URL IS DEFINED HERE"